# How to commit MySql table name as variable in python?

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I want to create a new mysqldb table for each unique user, but i'm getting errors:

> 1.'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
>
> 2.Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
>
> 3.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Text'(
> `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
> `UserName` text NOT NULL' at line 1

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name}".format(table_name=belekas), (belekas) + """(
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`UserName` text NOT NULL,
`Data` date NOT NULL,
`Laikas` time NOT NULL,
`KeyStrokes` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)   ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8""")
con.commit()
c.execute("INSERT INTO {table_name} VALUES (id, %s, Data, Laikas, %s)".format(table_name=belekas),
          (belekas, vartotojas, tekstas))
con.commit()
```

I tried using:

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + vartotojas + """(
```

and this:

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + repr(vartotojas.decode('utf-8')) + """(
```

and this:

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {this_table}".format(this_table=vartotojas), (vartotojas.encode("utf-8")) + """(
```

Can someone suggest solution for this problem?

Comment: there is a blank missing between EXISTS and "

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need separate tables per user - this seems a very bad design decision that may give you big problems in the future.

Comment: @PaulF is probably correct. But putting that matter aside for the time being, it appears that **vartojas** is a byte string. The essential way of converting that to a string is to use the **str** function. You can use this function's **encode** method. You should examine the contents of the encoded version of variable, to ensure that there are no extraneous extra characters (especially at the beginning or end).